# How to discover private bitbucket repos

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-cli

Using bash, is there some command line utility I can use to discover bitbucket repos for my organization? Something like this:

```
key="$HOME/.ssh/key"

bitbucket --ssh-key="$key" --discover-repos --org='teros' | while read line; do
  echo "$line"
done
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Just need the urls for all our bitbucket repos so I can run vulnerability testing on each one

Comment: I think using `GET api.bucketbucket.org/2.0/<org>/repos` or something like that can give me some JSON to work with

Comment: specifically with curl you just use your emai/password like `curl -u <bitbucket-email>:<bitbucket-pwd>`

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't be able to use SSH for it, but the Bitbucket Cloud APIs would let you see a list of repositories where the given user has access:

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/user/permissions/repositories

That won't show you any repos where you don't have access, of course - they wouldn't really be private repos if you could still see them - but it should let you see what's out there.